# Can one change templates arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

I have written the following  Matrix class:

```
template <typename T, size_t r, size_t c> //r=rows,c=cols of the Matrix
class Matrix {
public:
    size_t row = 0;
    size_t col = 0;
    T *data;

    template <size_t L>
    Matrix<T, r, L> operator*(const Matrix<T, c, L> &other) const;

    template <size_t r, size_t c>
    Matrix &operator=(const Matrix<T, r, c> &other)

    // ...
};
```

I overrode some operators to do some basic arithmetic and everything seems to work properly - however there is an issue which I don't know how to address properly: Given the following lines of code:

```
  Matrix<double, 1, 4> m1(1.2);
  Matrix<double, 4, 1> m2(1.2);
  Matrix<double, 2, 2> m3; // problematic line
  m3 = m1 * m2;
```

`m3` is of type `Matrix<double, 2, 2>`, is correctly computed, has one row and one col and carries the `5.76`, but stays as `Matrix<double, 2, 2>`. The change of its number of rows and cols is not reflected in its template parameters. Naturally however I would expect the type to be also informative regarding its content.

I don't suppose one cannot turn a `Matrix<double, 2, 2>` suddenly into a `Matrix<double, 1, 1>` Matrix, but maybe there is a good solution I just cannot think of now.

And replace:

```
 template <size_t r, size_t c> void replace(const Matrix<T, r, c> &other) {
    delete[] data; 
    row = other.row; //number of rows of a matrix
    col = other.col; //number of cols of a matrix
    data = new T[col * row]; // data contains all the elements of my matrix
    for (size_t i = 0; i < row * col; i++)
      data[i] = other.data[i];
  }
```

Comment: This is pretty confusing. What exactly did you expect `m3` to do? Also is `Matrix` self written or from `Eigen`?

Comment: Definitely not Eigen, as Eigen will break at compile time. You need to add checks in your expression templates, this should not even compile.

Comment: what does the operator * look like?

Comment: There is no way in normal matrix operations for a 1x4 matrix multiplied by a 4x1 matrix to give a 2x2 matrix.    It will (depending on order of operations) give either a 4x4 or a 1x1.    Given a 4x4 matrix, I guess you could specify a transformation to a 2x2.

Comment: Storing size information in the type is a very good idea. You just have to adopt initialization and `auto` instead of pre-declaring your variables. Alternatively, you can use `decltype(m1 * m2)`.

Comment: The resulting dimension of a matrix multiplication is well defined, so you can simply write your operator to return the expected type. But no, you can't convert it to some other matrix type without an appropriate constructor, which in the case of your example would be ludicrous.

Comment: I added now the suggested code snippets containing further information.

Comment: Okay not quite so ludicrous on second read. You could basically create a function to reshape the matrix (you may want two varieties: row-major and column-major). That can be templated and would return an appropriate type to match the assignment.

Comment: @paddy, that sounds interesting, however how does one do that? I am also not sure what you mean with shape: My matrix does have the correct shape, just not the right type.

Comment: `m3 = (m1 * m2).reshape<2,2>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your declaration

```
template <typename T, size_t r, size_t c> //r=rows,c=cols of the Matrix
class Matrix {
public:
    template <size_t L>
    Matrix<T, r, L> operator*(const Matrix<T, c, L> &other) const;

    template <size_t r, size_t c> // BEWARE: shadowing
    Matrix &operator=(const Matrix<T, r, c> &other);

    // ...
};
```

we can guess what happens.

```
Matrix<double, 1, 4> m1(1.2);
Matrix<double, 4, 1> m2(1.2);
m1 * m2; // (1)
```

`(1)` calls `Matrix<double, 1, 4>::operator*<1>(Matrix<double, 4, 1> const&)`. It result has then type `Matrix<double, 1, 1>`.

```
Matrix<double, 2, 2> m3;
m3 = /* (2) */ m1 * m2;
```

`(2)` calls `Matrix<double, 2, 2>::operator=<1, 1>(Matrix<double, 1, 1> const&)`. This is a problem.

A solution would be to ensure `operator=` can only be called with another matrix of the *right* size:

```
template <typename T, size_t r, size_t c> //r=rows,c=cols of the Matrix
class Matrix {
public:
    template <size_t L>
    Matrix<T, r, L> operator*(Matrix<T, c, L> const& other) const;

    Matrix &operator=(Matrix const& other);

    // ...
};
```

You could even allow type conversions:

```
template<class U>
Matrix &operator=(Matrix<U, r, c> const& other);
```

---

Finally, you might want to use `auto`:

```
Matrix<double, 1, 4> m1(1.2);
Matrix<double, 4, 1> m2(1.2);
auto m3 = m1 * m2; // m3 is Matrix<double, 1, 1>
```

Comment: That is basically spot on. I like your suggestion to change the =operator and check, if the assignment is valid. Maybe I did view the problem from the wrong angle: If I create a Matrix like `m3`, then I already have to know, what it has to look like and what it's going to do. To me it looks now, I cannot work around the auto OR specific in advance what I expect that is going to happen - how the matrix looks like.